# Can You Convert a Keras Model From Json Format to h5?

Tags: json, tensorflow, keras

I am having a pretrained model in json format but i want to use it in python app, is there a way of converting this model to keras h5 Model format?

Answer (score 0):

As per https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/, it should look something like:

```
json_file_path = "/path/to/json"
with open(json_file_path, "r") as json_file:
    json_savedModel= json_file.read()
model_json = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(json_savedModel)
model_json.save("model_name.h5", save_format="hf")
```

Edit: And then to load the h5 model:

```
h5_file = "/path/to/model_name.h5"
model_h5 = tf.keras.models.load_model(h5_file)
```

Comment: It is bringing this error when i try to run that code. --> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Can you update your question with your code for better help? Otherwise there's no telling what's really going on.

Comment: @derrick-zziwa updated the post to possibly help with actually loading a json